# Skip certain cells when adding values to DGV column

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview

I can not get this to work. I am trying to populate column 2 with values from txt file and to skip cells that has no value in column 1 but without skipping data from text file.

This is what I get :

[image]

And code that I'm using :

```
Dim fileName = "X:\2013\NKT13\FI-ZL\BU.rev"
        Dim lineCount = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Length
        Dim lines() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)


        For i As Integer = 0 To lineCount
            Dim RM001 As String = lines(i).Replace(".", "")
            Dim LBS001() As String = RM001.Split(New String() {";"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim Val = LBS001(1)
            Dim Val2 = LBS001(2)
            If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value Is Nothing Then
                'MsgBox(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Index)
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
            Else
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = LBS001(0)
                Next
            End If
Next
```

In code above line `If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value Is Nothing` is not working. When that line is replaced with this one `If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = ""`, I get this :

[image]

Here A201A is missing and for every empty row in column1 1 result is going to be skipped.
How to populate column 2 with data from txt file so that only rows are skipped not results.

EDIT : 
*I've tried something else and it works for the first empty cell in column 2, but when it comes to a second...it skips one data from array and then continues normally until reaches another empty cell. Example : A201A...A224A (everything OK)...blank cell(skipped)...A205 in OK but in 206 cell it puts A207A.*

Now, this code below works too, thanks to Steve.

```
Dim Dat2() As String = Split(start1(0), Environment.NewLine)
        Dim Dat2A() As String = Split(Dat2(0), ";")
        Dim Dat2B() As String = Split(Dat2(1), ";")


        Dim fileName = "X:\2013\NKT13\FI-ZL\BU.rev"
        Dim lineCount = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Length
        Dim lines() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)

    Dim a As Integer = 0
        For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2

             If DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value <> "" Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = Dat2(a)

            a += 1
        Else
            DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = ""

        End If
            End If
        Next
```

EDIT 2 : 
Thanks to Steve...I've changed code a bit and it works. Only problem is I am missing two lines in `lineCount` I think because of every DGV row that is skipped.

```
        Dim fileName = "X:\2013\NKT13\FI-ZL\BU.rev"
    Dim lineCount = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Length
    Dim lines() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
    MsgBox(lineCount)
    Dim i2 As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To lineCount
        Dim RM001 As String = lines(i2).Replace(".", "")
        Dim LBS001() As String = RM001.Split(New String() {";"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim Val = LBS001(1)
        Dim Val2 = LBS001(2)
        If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value <> "" Then
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = LBS001(0)

            Next
            i2 += 1
        Else
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing now is using `i` to read the line and `i` to write to your grid. What you need is another variable like `i2` that you increment manually when you set the value in a grid, or need to skip a line in the grid.

```
Dim i2 as Int32 = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To lineCount
  Dim RM001 As String = lines(i).Replace(".", "")
  Dim LBS001() As String = RM001.Split(New String() {";"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim Val = LBS001(1)
  Dim Val2 = LBS001(2)
  If DataGridView1.Rows(i2).Cells(1).Value Is Nothing Then
     'MsgBox(DataGridView1.Rows(i2).Index)
     DataGridView1.Rows(i2).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
  Else
     For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        DataGridView1.Rows(i2).Cells(2).Value = LBS001(0)
     Next
     i2 += 1
  End If
Next
```

EDIT: After further review and edits by the OP, this is a better answer:

```
Dim fileName = "X:\2013\NKT13\FI-ZL\BU.rev"
Dim lines() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
Dim lineCount = lines.Length
Dim a As Integer = 0
For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    If DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value <> "" Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = lines(a)
        a += 1
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value = ""        
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I still get results like in the first image. Btw after a while I realized that I need another variable for the data. I have edited my original post just seconds before your answer...maybe you could help me further? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you resetting `a = x` when the cell is empty. Your basically telling it to do the same thing it was doing before. Take a closer look at the code I provided, you will see a big difference in what we are doing.

Comment: First of all, I was avoiding loops with DGVs because I am kind of new to programming so I have to look at the code for some time until I see an error. Anyways I've tried you code and got all the values in column 2, but no skipped rows, this line doesn't work "DataGridView1.Rows(i2).Cells(1).Value Is Nothing". Also I've enabled msgbox just to test it and nothing it ignores empty cells completely.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not answering the question on how to see if a cell is empty, I was simply showing how you could 'skip certain cells'. To find out what the value of a cell is so you can properly program your `IF` statement, put in a breakpoint and see what the value is.

Comment: Sorry, can not get it to work, it seems to me that Var i2 is outside of loop and is 0, until reaches cell in col2 with value and that is not going to happen because it's always 0. Maybe I'm mistaken...

Comment: Looking at the edit above, I assume you are not using `lines()` anymore but instead you are using `Dat2()'. So, in your first `IF`, replace `a = x` with `a += 1` and in your `else` get rid of all the `a` and `x` and `IF` stuff so you just have the one line that sets the cell value to an empty string.

Comment: I've edited (EDIT 2) my org.post with new code...adapted your code and it works, but now lineCount is short by 2 even though it counts right before the loop starts. I guess those row that are skipped somehow cuts that number by 2. Can you suggest something other then adding +2 in lineCount, 'cause in most cases that I'm going to use this code I won't know how many rows are going to be skipped?

Comment: Did you try the change to EDIT1 that I suggested. After looking at it a little harder, there is a big issue with My answer and EDIT2 in that you need to loop through the datagrid within the linecount loop. Your edit1 made this not necessary and my comments should have made it work as expected. I will post another answer showing full code since this is getting confusing.

Comment: I can not believe it...so much frustration, and with that "little" change everything is ok. Thank you so much for you effort. I'll change EDIT 1.